# Is it passive agressive to just write "ok" after an deleted message?

Tags: friends, chatting

Today I asked a girlfriend of mine a question over Whatsapp. I don't think the message matters but, it was along those lines:

> Did we plan to go to the cinema next week?

I then found the calender entry for the cinema visit and she didn't read the question, so I though I could just delete my Question and no one will matter.

1-2 Hours later she just wrote me "ok" without any comment.

I think this is very passive aggressive but I am not sure if I'm just overreacting.

I asked her what she means with "ok", but she didn't reply.

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we have no way of knowing what your friend thinks or intends.

Comment: Fyi, deleting messages on Whatsapp does not do what you think it does. The Message is only deleted for you, NOT for the other person. - There is a "delete for everyone" Option, but that does not work if the recipient has an older Version of Whatsapp.

Comment: Especially with what Patta told us in mind, it's always a good idea to not jump to conclusions.

Answer (score 4):

Before rushing to judgement, consider alternative explanations. If she is reading WhatsApp on her phone, she might have seen the whole message in a notification on the top of the screen, which means she's read it but it is marked as unread for you. And she might then have written a quick 'ok' reply later without taking the time to notice that you'd deleted it.